# Javascript objects and asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, oop, asynchronous

I'm trying a more object oriented approach with javascript and have implemented a class with some methods through the use of class.prototype.

But I have a problem.

I tried to use a method from myclass as the success function of an ajax call. The issue is I can't use `this` withing that method when is called back by ajax. I.E:

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function(data)
{
this.data = data; /* in here this is the window object */
}
var myClass = new MyClass();
$.ajax:
    success:myClass.myMethod;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Full function to try

> am not i am

method

```
    function MyClass()
{
    this.name="myclass";
};

MyClass.prototype.print = function()
{
    alert(this.name);
};

var myAjax = function(context_,func)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"www.google.com",
        type: "GET",
        context:context_,
        complete:function(data){
            func(data);
        }
    });
};


var refreshGroups = function(groups)
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myAjax(myClass,myClass.print);
    return;
}
```

Result: alert is empty

Comment: Do you mean:

`$.ajax({
    success:myClass.myMethod;
});`?

Comment: Javascript isn't OO, so the abstraction breaks pretty quickly.  The `myMethod` function doesn't know it's meant to only act on your class, it's just a method. You will need to wrap the call in an anonymous function that calls the method on your object. Replace `myClass.myMethod` with `function(){myClass.myMethod();}`

Comment: @david JavaScript *is* OO, it just lacks bound methods because it binds `this` in a weird way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"The issue is I can't use this withing that method when is called back by ajax."*

Use the `context:` property of the `$.ajax` call.

```
$.ajax({
    url:...,
    context: myClass,
    success: myClass.myMethod
});
```

or use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy)...

```
$.ajax({
    url:...,
    success: $.proxy(myClass, 'myMethod')
});
```

---

Given the updated code, you'd need to change `func(data)` to be called from the calling context that you set using `context:`, so you do `this.func(data)`...

```
var myAjax = function(context_,func)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"www.google.com",
        type: "GET",
        context:context_,
        complete:function(data){
            this.func(data);
        }
    });
};
```

...but since you're not doing anything in that anonymous function other than calling the function you passed, and passing on the argument, you could just do `complete:func`...

```
var myAjax = function(context_,func)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"www.google.com",
        type: "GET",
        context:context_,
        complete:func
    });
};
```

...and the calling context of `func` will be set to the object you passed, and the `data` argument will still be passed to the function.

---

Of course, this really isn't an issue the way your code works, because you already have a closed reference to your context, so you could just as well skip passing the `func`, and just get it right from your object...

```
var myAjax = function(context_) // <-- no function argument needed
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"www.google.com",
        type: "GET",
        complete:function(data){
            context_.print(data);
        }
    });
};

var refreshGroups = function(groups)
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myAjax(myClass); // <--just pass the object
    return;
}
```

Comment: Dang it I need to write this on the back of my hand or something :-)

Comment: @doubter: I would need to see more code. What you've provided looks like a small fragment of the actual. Post more code and I may be able to help.

Comment: @amnotiam updated if you could take a look it would be great :)

Comment: @doubter: You would need this... `complete:function(data){ this.func(data); }`, or even better, just this... `complete:func`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Methods in JavaScript aren't really bound in any deep way to object properties; they're just values.  When you reference the function like that, the fact that `this` was involved when you set up the ajax call is completely lost.

There's a new-ish API to help:

```
success: this.myMethod.bind(this) // or myClass.myMethod.bind(myClass) ...
```

That `.bind()` method (from the Function prototype in newer browsers) returns *another* function that will call your method ensuring that `this` is correctly set up on that call.

There's a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) version of "bind" available at the MDN website (and there are others too).  You can, alternatively, do the same thing explicitly:

```
var obj = this;
$.ajax({
  // ...
  success: function() { obj.myMethod(); },
  // ...
});
```

That "obj" variable is necessary to hold the outer-context value of `this`.